# ASP.NET MVC 4 - RedirectToAction not working in Explorer after deploying to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, iis-7

I'm having an issue with a number of redirects in an intranet application I'm currently building. Built using ASP.NET MVC4.

When running the application locally after debugging in Visual Studio, it works fine in all browsers, but deploying to IIS 7 on our development server and running it remotely from there causes some of my RedirectToAction statements to stop working but only in Internet Explorer.

The first of the following statements does nothing, it just refreshes the current page, while the second redirects properly:

```
if (Command == "CompleteFollow")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("CreateFollowup", "ECHO", new { id = resolution.complaint_id });
    }
else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "ECHO", new { id = resolution.complaint_id });
    }
```

Both pages exist and the redirects are working in both Chrome and Firefox, but not Internet explorer.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how it can be fixed?

Comment: If you call it using Ajax post (or $post) it will not work. Show more code to understand an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was found:

It was an Internet Explorer compatibility mode issue.

It was fixed by adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

to the head section of _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Hey in my case opposite is happening. When running the application locally in debug mode the application redirects properly in IE but not in Chrome and firefox. Any Idea??